# Create XML Document that end with slash ('<test />' instead of '<test></test>')

Tags: java, xml, stax

I need to create XML Document that end with slash if XML element is in one line (`<test/>` instead of `<test></test>`)

Here is the sample code to create XML Docs as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<cars><supercars company="Ferrari">
<carname type="formula one"></carname>
<carname type="sports"></carname>
</supercars></cars>
```

But i want the XML docs should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<cars><supercars company="Ferrari">
<carname type="formula one"/>
<carname type="sports"/>
</supercars></cars>
```

Note that, there is no </carname>

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

public class StAXCreateXMLDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

     XMLOutputFactory xMLOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();    
     XMLStreamWriter xMLStreamWriter =  xMLOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);

     xMLStreamWriter.writeStartDocument();
     xMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement("cars");

     xMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement("supercars");            
     xMLStreamWriter.writeAttribute("company", "Ferrari");

     xMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement("carname");          
     xMLStreamWriter.writeAttribute("type", "formula one");

     xMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement();

     xMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement("carname");          
     xMLStreamWriter.writeAttribute("type", "sports");

     xMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement();

     xMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement();
     xMLStreamWriter.writeEndDocument();

     xMLStreamWriter.flush();
     xMLStreamWriter.close();

     String xmlString = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();

     stringWriter.close();

     System.out.println(xmlString);

  } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: you'd need to tell java that you want to create a singleton tag. without a dtd, java would simply assume that the tag you're creating ISN'T a singleton, and can contain other tags, and give you the `<foo></foo>` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using `XMLStreamWriter.writeEmptyElement`:

Instead of

```
 xMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement("carname");
 xMLStreamWriter.writeAttribute("type", "formula one");
 xMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement();
```

use

```
xMLStreamWriter.writeEmptyElement("carname");
xMLStreamWriter.writeAttribute("type", "formula one");
```